# Same differential expression but different values

Tags: calculus

Sorry if this a basic question, but I found two different expressions for the same $\mathrm dV$.

1. $\mathrm dV$ is the volume of a small cuboid, made of three different sides $\mathrm dx$, $\mathrm dy$, and $\mathrm dz$. Hence, $\mathrm dV=\mathrm dx\cdot\mathrm dy\cdot\mathrm dz$
2. $V=xyz$ for a cuboid with sides $x$, $y$ and $z$; so $\mathrm dV=\mathrm d(xyz)$;
   Now apply the product rule to get $\mathrm dV=xy\mathrm dz+yz\mathrm
       dx+xz\mathrm dy$.

In both the derivations the only formula we have used is $\text{Volume of a cuboid}=\text{Product of its three sides}$. Then, how can the same $\mathrm dV$ refer to two completely different expressions?

I at least don't see any way how $\mathrm dx\cdot\mathrm dy\cdot\mathrm dz$ can equal $ xy\mathrm dz+yz\mathrm dx+xz\mathrm dy$. Is this even possible?

Comment: It is important to note that the differential of the *function* $V(x,y,z) = xyz$ at the origin is the best *linear* approximation to that function there. Since this function is very non-linear at the origin, $dV = 0$ there. This is basically a notational issue, where $dV$ could be interpreted as a 1-form (the total derivative of $V$) or as a 3-form (the volume form of a cube), and these are very different objects.

Comment: @AlexProvost Oh, thanks! Could you elaborate on what is meant by "1-form"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form Basically, the 1-form $df$ at a point $\vec c$ takes as input a displacement $\vec h$ from that point and outputs the linear variation in $f$ from $\vec c$ to $\vec c + \vec h$. For example, at $\vec c = (1,1,1)$, the volume (of a cube with corners $0$ and $\vec c$) is $f(\vec c) = 1$. The linear variation of the volume when moving from $(1,1,1)$ to $(2,1,1)$ is $df(1,0,0) = 1$, which equals the real variation. However, if you move to $(2,2,1)$, then the linear variation is $df(1,1,0) = 2$, whereas the real variation is $f(2,2,1) - f(1,1,1) = 3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They two different things. $V = x y z$ is the total volume enclosed from the origin to a point $\boldsymbol{r} = \pmatrix{x & y & z}$.

The physical interpretation of ${\rm d}V = {\rm d}(x y z)$ is finding how much *the total volume* changes as the location $\boldsymbol{r}$ changes.

[image: dv1]

The total volume of the three extensions above is

$$ {\rm d}V = y z {\rm d}x + x z {\rm d}y + x y {\rm d}z $$

But just because you named it ${\rm d}V$ doesn't mean it is the same as the infinitesimal volume element ${\rm d}V = {\rm d}x\, {\rm d}y\, {\rm d}z$

[image: dV2]

---

In general, to derive ${\rm d}V$ given a solid described by all points $\boldsymbol{p}(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ within a domain you perform the following calculation

$$ {\rm d}V = \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{p}}{\partial x_1} \cdot \left( \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{p}}{\partial x_2} \times \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{p}}{\partial x_3} \right) {\rm d}x_1\,{\rm d}x_2\,{\rm d} x_3 $$

<sub>Where $\cdot$ is the vector dot product, and $\times$ the vector cross product. $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ are *any* three independent quantities used to describe the location of all points in the volume.</sub>

The above can be derived from the geometry of the problem, and the volume of the tetrahedron volume described by three vectors.

For example, you are integrating over a cylinder with $\boldsymbol{p}(r,\theta,z) = \pmatrix{r \cos \theta \\ r \sin\theta \\ z}$ and $r=0 \ldots R$, $\theta = 0 \ldots 2 \pi$ and $z = 0 \ldots \ell$.

$${\rm d}V = \frac{ \partial \pmatrix{r \cos \theta \\ r \sin\theta \\ z}}{\partial r} \cdot \left( \frac{ \partial \pmatrix{r \cos \theta \\ r \sin\theta \\ z}}{\partial \theta} \times \frac{\partial \pmatrix{r \cos \theta \\ r \sin\theta \\ z}}{\partial z} \right) {\rm d}r\, {\rm d}\theta\, {\rm d}z $$

$$ {\rm d}V = \pmatrix{ \cos \theta \\ \sin\theta \\ 0} \cdot \left( \pmatrix{- \sin \theta \\ \cos\theta \\ 0} \times \pmatrix{0 \\ 0 \\ 1}  \right) {\rm d}r\, {\rm d}\theta\, {\rm d}z $$ $$\boxed{{\rm d}V =  r {\rm d}r\, {\rm d}\theta\, {\rm d}z}$$

Comment: "total volume of the three extensions above" yep exactly what I was looking for! +1 and thanks! :D

Comment: In the last equation I believe you have taken the scalar triple product of the individual change in $r$ vector with respect to each dimension $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$, that gives you the volume of the cuboid. But what do those three $\mathrm dx_1\mathrm dx_2\mathrm dx_3$ at the end stand for?

Comment: To describe the total solid domain you need three coordinates, like $x,y,z$ or $r,\theta,z$ or whatever. Those are the $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$.

Comment: I get it, but I was asking what does the $\mathrm dx_1\mathrm dx_2\mathrm dx_3$ stand for? If it stands for the volume enclosed by a small cuboid formed by $dx$ and $dy$ and $dz$ as the edges, then what does $dV$ in that last equation represent?

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: I'm sorry sir. I understand your calculation. But I wish to know what exactly does the $\mathrm dr~\mathrm d\theta~\mathrm dz$ represent physically?

Comment: Think of a small slice of a cylinder with angle ${\rm d}\theta$ and thickness ${\rm d}z$. Now slice a cord out of that to make a small "arc" volume of ${\rm d}V =  r {\rm d}r\, {\rm d}\theta\, {\rm d}z$ if the width of the arc is ${\rm d}r$. Think of it as, ${\rm d}x = {\rm d}r$ and ${\rm d}y = r {\rm d} \theta$ as two sides of the volume element.

Comment: I got it thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Euclidean space, the volume element is given by the product of the differentials of the Cartesian coordinates, viz $$dV=dx\,dy\,dz$$

However, what you have done in the second part is seemingly take a *function* $f(x, y, z)=xyz$ and composed its total differential 
\begin{align}
df &= f_x \,dx + f_y\, dy + f_z\, dz \\
&=yz\, dx + xz\, dy + xy\, dz
\end{align}

They are both very different objects.